# How to set custom colors in these areas for IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, background-color

I'm new to IntelliJ, and I'm trying to setup some custom colors, but in the IDEA, I couldn't fine where the colors are for these areas, could some one show me how to locate these colors in the setting ?

[image]

Comment: This background color is not customizable via the IDE settings. You will need to create a custom color theme plugin, see [Custom UI Themes](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/themes-intro.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Way too complex, I would hope it's just as easy as a right-mouse click, in a drop down menu, select "Change Color" and set my custom color for that part of the component, why no one has thought about this, much easier for the user.